# Optimisation - finding the minimum time

Tags: calculus

[image]

so the function i used to get part a) is : $22n + 60(1/2)^n $ where $n$ is the number of 22 month periods.

however for part b) , why isn't the answer $c=60$? Using the same formula as part a, I set $n =0$ such that $60 = 22(0) + c(1/2)^n$

any hints or suggestions??

Comment: It seems like it should be either $60.0$ or $59.9$

Comment: You want to find $c$ such that $22n + c(1/2)^n$ is minimised at $n = 0$. This $c$ cannot be $60$, because you know that $22n + 60(1/2)^n$ is minimised at $n \approx 0.92$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan both of those answers weren't correct

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist but at $n=0$  the equation would just be $60 = c$ would it not?

Comment: @lohboys why would it be? I don’t know why you set the left-hand side to $60$, as the number $60$ is irrelevant to part (b).

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist since she is buying the computers immediately wouldnt the amount of months be 60 since it would take 5 years if she bought them now?

Comment: @lohboys No. It would take $c$ months if she bought them now, in part (b).

Comment: @lohboys , if she bought them after $22$ months, it would take a total of $22+30=52$ months which is smaller than $60$ months.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan 52 doesnt seem to be correct either

Comment: I am not saying that it is. It should be $43$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan oh my apologies, still not correct though

Comment: NP , was $43$ correct?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan unfortunately not

Comment: Eh no problem, still searching for a solution. Could you perhaps add a link?

Comment: Oh wait it is $43.9$ months. My rounding was offtrack

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist im still unsure what you're suggesting sorry, but my equation i mentioned before is the correct starting point right?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan tried 43.9, didnt work

Comment: Oh, it will probably be an exponential equation. Could you add a link?

Comment: link to? @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: The question. Are you doing it on a website?

Comment: its for a student assignment, i cant share access to it @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: No problem. I will keep trying, hopefully receiving a solution.

Comment: The answer is not $43.9$. It is smaller than that. It is true that if $c=0$, then she should buy the computers immediately. (If the problem takes no time to solve, then delaying the purchase of computers will just delay the time till the problem is solved.) However, suppose that $c = 1$. Would she not also want to buy the computers right away in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The researcher's objective function is to choose $n$ that minimises

$$ 22n + c \left( \frac 12 \right)^n. $$

We know that the optimal $n$, which we'll call $n^*$ satisfies

$$ 22 = c \left( \frac 12 \right)^{n^*} \ln 2, $$

so that

$$ n^* = \log_2 \left( \frac{c \ln 2}{22} \right). $$

In part (a), you had that $c = 60$. Hence, the optimal $n$ must be

$$ \log_2 \left( \frac{60 \ln 2}{22} \right) \approx 0.9187. $$

This gives you an answer of $\approx 20.2$ months, as you've found in part (a).

Now, in part (b), you wish to find the $c$ for which the optimal $n$ is zero. We know that the time-minimising $n^*$ satisfies

$$ n^* = \log_2 \left( \frac{c \ln 2}{22} \right). $$

What must $c$ be so that we have $n^*=0$ in the equation above?

Comment: right so 31.8 is what i got and this seems to be the correct answer! greatly appreciated all you help, I'll take some time now to digest what you have provided

Comment: care to explain $22= c(1/2)^n * ln2$?

Comment: @lohboys This comes from the first-order condition for the objective function. Did you not use a similar expression to find your answer to part (a)?

Comment: I used my graphics calculator to differentiate it originally - I just differentiated by hand and became aware of a new formula $a^b = e^ (bln(a)) $ - now i can see how you got to that answer